# Substituir URL numa tag <embed>

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma tag `<embed>` assim no meu HTML:

```
<embed class="flash" src="http://example.com/swf/10/nome.swf">
```

Eu queria achar um jeito de mudar o endereço para `http://example.com/swf/5/nome.swf`.

Ignorando as flashvars, como posso fazer isso em JavaScript? Preciso usar isso no Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se funciona:

Obs: pressupõe que você tenha incluído o `Jquery` na sua página.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("embed.flash").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/10/", "/5/"));
      });
    });
</script>

<embed class="flash" src="http://example.com/swf/10/nome.swf">
```

Comment: Bem, acho que não deu certo, mas isso deve ser um problema no próprio site, ele só ativa o swf após executar `status_toggler(); launch_chatter();`. Acho que por isso, eu deva procurar uma forma de mudar essa função, mas não sei se aqui é o melhor lugar para perguntar. Ainda assim, obrigado.

Comment: Ah sim. Também inclua o AJAX na página.

Comment: @Carlos, "ajax"? acho que vc refere-se a "jquery"...

Comment: Bem lembrado, eu quis dizer Jquery, já corrigi :)